# How to deal with records invalidated due to adding filter criteria on lookup field?

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I have an object A which has lookup relationship to object B.

The lookup relationship field on object A is not required.

I recently added filter criteria to this lookup relationship field.
(Added a custom checkbox field name Inactive on object B. Only active records of object B should be available for selection.)

Adding this criteria invalidated some existing records where the related record has now been set as Inactive.

This is causing an error whenever user saves the record by changing value in any field.

Error: Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.

What are some ways to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means 1 of the two things.

1. You have invalid data that breaks constraints set by lookup filter.
2. Your lookup filter is wrong.

That being said, you can make lookup filter as progressive. That means it will only work for Records created after a particular period. You can do that by adding a date filter. This would still allow you to save/edit old record.

[image]

In the image I posted, the filter will work only for new opportunities, for old opportunites filter would be non existent.

Comment: Thanks for lesson on making lookup filters progressive. is it possible to specify those dates taking values from custom labels ?

Comment: No you cannot refer custom lable directly. But you can create a formula field on that object that will refer to custom label.  DATEVALUE( $Label.Mydate ) and then use that forumula field in lookup filter